# didSimulatePhysics to animate a ball, taking 45% of CPU

Tags: performance, swift, animation, physics, sprite-kit

According to my time profiler this is taking 45% of my cpu usage: have tried to optimize, and someone on stack overflow -- recommended to post here. Time profiler says 99% of the time is spent on the closing brace of the `world.enumerateChildNodesWithName`

```
override func didSimulatePhysics() {

        world.enumerateChildNodesWithName("//ball*") {
            node, stop in
            let ball = node as! Ball
            ball.regulateSpeed()
            if let body = ball.physicsBody {
                if (body.velocity.speed() > 0.01) {
                    ball.zRotation = body.velocity.angle() - self.offset
                }
            }
        }

        if let p = currentPlayer {
            centerWorldOnPosition(p.centerPosition())
        } else if playerLayer.children.count > 0 {
            let p = playerLayer.children.first! as! Player
            centerWorldOnPosition(p.centerPosition())
        } else {
            centerWorldOnPosition(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        }
    }
```

Comment: enumerateChildNodesWithName may be taking a lot of time to perform,  if you took this out of the function,  how is your CPU usage?